# Run-time error '2110':` Microsoft Office Access can't move the focus to the control

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have designed a form in MS-Access-2007 having two textbox `SearchFor`, `SrchText` and a ListBox `SearchResults`. This form is used to search records from a query and result apears in `SearchResults`.

`SearchFor` is used to put values to search

`SrchText` is used as a query parameter

`SearchResults` is used to appear searched values

This code is working perfect but when I put any text starting with "i" in textbox `SearchFor` an error prompt `Run-time error '2110': Microsoft Office Access can't move the focus to the control SearchResults`.

```
Private Sub SearchFor_Change()

'Create a string (text) variable
    Dim vSearchString As String

'Populate the string variable with the text entered in the Text Box SearchFor
    vSearchString = SearchFor.Text

'Pass the value contained in the string variable to the hidden text box SrchText,
'that is used as the sear4ch criteria for the Query QRY_SearchAll
    SrchText.Value = vSearchString

'Requery the List Box to show the latest results for the text entered in Text Box SearchFor
    Me.SearchResults.Requery

'Tests for a trailing space and exits the sub routine at this point
'so as to preserve the trailing space, which would be lost if focus was shifted from Text Box SearchFor
    If Len(Me.SrchText) <> 0 And InStr(Len(SrchText), SrchText, " ", vbTextCompare) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Set the focus on the first item in the list box
    Me.SearchResults = Me.SearchResults.ItemData(1)
    Me.SearchResults.SetFocus

'Requery the form to refresh the content of any unbound text box that might be feeding off the record source of  the List Box
    DoCmd.Requery

'Returns the cursor to the the end of the text in Text Box SearchFor
    Me.SearchFor.SetFocus

    If Not IsNull(Len(Me.SearchFor)) Then
        Me.SearchFor.SelStart = Len(Me.SearchFor)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you saying it works properly if the text starts with any other letter?

Comment: Yes, it works properly if the text starts with any other letter.

Comment: You've tried every other letter?

Comment: @nicomp yes, I have tried all other letters.

Comment: Review http://accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=35159. Are you trying to code a 'find as you type' functionality? Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppFindAsUTypeCode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution, but I still don't know why this working.

Open the form, go into design view, highlight the search box and open the property sheet. Under the Other tab, there is an option for 'Allow AutoCorrect'. Turn that to No and lowercase "i" finally works.

Comment: This must be a data issue.

Comment: i have the same issue but with a button. You have any ideas for a possible solution?